# Limiting which printers a Remote Desktop Services user sees

Tags: terminal-server, printer, remote-desktop-services, shared-printers

I have an RDS server with about a dozen printers installed.  Is there a way to remove all buta few certain printers for a particular user?  I don't mean that I want to "secure" the other printers to keep them from printing to them, but literally filter which printers appear in their available printers list.

Comment: Heh, even if there's no official way to do this, there must be a hack, because now I'm having the opposite problem - I've added a printer and only the admin can see it, not the users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, printers are either configured for the machine or in the user profile. Any printers configured on the machine will be visible to all users, whereas printers configured in the user profile will be visible to only that user. It's the same idea as how the desktop and Start menu work.

If you want users to only see printers that are relevant to them, you should be configuring all printers inside the user profile. So the first step is uninstalling the printers from the remote desktop server, and putting them on a print server. Then either manually configure the user profiles, or use Group Policy to automatically configure the user profiles.